# What are our specific abbreviations and terms?

Tags: discussion

Newcomers to PLDI are often compelled to ask what many of our abbreviations and terms mean. Let us list them here so this information always will be easily available.

Terms should be somewhat specific to this site. If they are [on the general SE list of abbreviations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) no need to copy them here.

Answer (score 5):

Please keep answers in alphabetical order.

- **ABI**: [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)
- **ADT**: either [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), or [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type)
- **ANF**: [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form), an intermdiate representation in which function arguments must be constants or variables
- **AOT**: [ahead-of-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation)
- **ASG**: [Abstract Semantic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_semantic_graph), a graph data structure representing the semantic meaning of the source code
- **AST**: [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), a tree data structure representing the structure of the source code
- **BNF**: [Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), used for defining formal grammars
- **CFG**: either [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), or [control-flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_graph)
- **CMP**: Chat Mini Poll, a quick question posed to other people in chat. Typically used for quick questions <s>about syntax</s> that would be considered too broad on the main site.
- **CPS**: [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), a form in which control-flow is represented by continuation functions
- **DSL**: [Domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_specific_language), a highly specialized language for a specific domain
- **EBNF**: [extended Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), used for defining formal grammars
- **Esolang**: An [esoteric programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language), a language intended as a experiment, joke, or a challenge; not for writing useful programs
- **FFI**: [Foreign Function Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface), any mechanism that allows calling functions in another language. See also ABI.
- **GADT**: [generalised algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_algebraic_data_type)
- **GC**: [Garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), or garbage collector
- [**GCC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection): the GNU Compiler Collection, an optimising compiler for various programming languages
- **GIL**: [global interpreter lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock)
- **IR**: an [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) of a program, between source code and a compiled result
- **JIT**: [just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)
- **LC**: [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)
- **LDQ:** Language Design Question, an informal question in chat. Initialism taken from Code Golf's main chat room, The Nineteenth Byte.
- [**LLVM**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM): a popular third-party compiler backend which can target a variety of processor architectures
- **LSP**: either [Language Server Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) or [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
- **PEG**: [Parsing Expression Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar), a kind of formal grammar
- **Praclang** or **PractLang**: A practical language that is intended for real world use, in contrast to experimental languages or esolangs
- **RTTI**: [run-time type information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)
- **RVSDG**: [Regionalized Value State Dependence Graph](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.05036), a kind of intermediate representation
- **SSA**: [Static single-assignment form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single-assignment_form), an intermediate representation in which each variable is assigned exactly once
- **STLC**: [Simply typed lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus)
- **TCO**: tail-call optimisation, applicable to functions whose last operation is a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)
- **TRO**: tail-recursion optimisation, a specialised form of tail-call optimisation when the tail call is a recursive call to the same function
- **UB**: [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning that the runtime behaviour of a program is not defined by the language specification
- **UFCS**: [Uniform Function Call Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax)
- **ULP**: [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) (also called "unit of least precision"), a measure of precision for floating-point numbers.
- **VM**: a [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine#Process_virtual_machines), unlike the normal meaning, in PL this typically just refers to a bytecode interpreter with some degree of abstraction of OS functions

Comment: Where does the term “praclang” originate? I was entirely unfamiliar with it, and searching the internet doesn’t really return any hits.

Comment: We use it a lot on CGCC, where esolangs are common enough that it needs to be specified if a language is intended to be actually used. It's been used in chat on this site too but some people didn't know what it meant which was actually the entire trigger for making this post